# Deleting last line from command line returns a weird character

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to delete the last line of the command line by calling `os.system("cls")` but that returns a weird symbol [image]

I tried using sub-processing to delete the last line but doing that returns an Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GameDev-Programming\Python\puzzles\puzzles 1\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    clear()
  File "D:\GameDev-Programming\Python\puzzles\puzzles 1\main.py", line 6, in clear
    x = call('clear' if os.name == 'posix' else 'cls')
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The code that i copied from the internet

```
from subprocess import call
import os


def clear():
    x = call('clear' if os.name == 'posix' else 'cls')


print("fa")

clear()
```

How do I fix these Issues? if I can't is there other ways to delete the last line of the Command-Line?

**Edit:**
Looks like the issue is from Pycharm(the ide im using)

I turned on the 'Emulate terminal in output console' in 'Run/Debug Configuration'

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also have tried this `'\x1b[1A'  '\x1b[2K'` [from quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-the-last-printed-line-in-Python-language)

Comment: Try running it from the command line. It works for me.

Comment: It's likely that the terminal built in to your IDE is having issues with the command. Have you tried running it via an actual command line?

Comment: @Kemp I tried using the `os.system("cls")` in the Cmd it worked looks like my ide is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The error message ...

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

... implies that the command you are trying to execute is not an external command. So it must be a command that is implemented by the shell. You need to add the *shell=True* argument:

```py
def clear():
    x = call('clear' if os.name == 'posix' else 'cls', shell=True)
```